# Difference between autoformat and autoindent

Tags: indentation, formatting, plugin-vim-autoformat

What is difference between autoformat and autoindent? What are most popular solutions in text formating in vim of both of these methods?

Answer (score 1):

As the name suggests, **autoindent** helps mainly in indenting source code, while **autoformat** can be used while editing text.

For more information, you can access vim help by typing `:help autoindent` and `:help autoformat`.

See this post for additional info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355834/how-can-i-autoformat-indent-c-code-in-vim. It also addresses the 2nd part of your question.

Vim wiki at wikia has pages on these topics too:
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indenting_source_code
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatic_formatting_of_paragraphs